# Error while trying to make my rspec 1.2 tests go faster on JRuby and Rails 2.3.10 using nailgun and spork

Tags: rspec, jruby, ruby-on-rails-2, spork, nailgun

I recently start using JRuby in my Rails 2.3 webapp. Since then, I have been experiencing slowness in my rspec tests... the test are taking too long to run since I switched to JRuby.

While using MRI, I never bothered to use spork in order to run my tests faster, but now I need to speed up the execution of my test.

First, I tried spork, but I did't worked out because:

1. **spork 0.9 RC** supports **jruby**, but does not support **rails 2.3**
   (it only supports **rails 3**)
2. **spork 0.8** supports **rails 2.3**, but does not support **jruby** I think it uses fork(), the **spork-0.8 gem** won't event
   install on **jruby**).

I tried to run my tests on **jruby**, **rails 2.3** and **spork 0.9 rc**, but it didn't worked, in fact there was a warning message saying that **spork 0.9 rc** only supports **rails >= 3.0**

Then I tried nailgun, I installed the nailgun gem in my jruby environment (**gem install nailgun**) and started the nailgun server (**ruby --ng-server** at the root of my app). 
Then I run one of my specs (**ruby --ng -S spec spec/lib/importacao_atividades_spec.rb**). The first time I executed the spec, it went just fine, but after that it kept raising **RuntimeError: invalid runtime**

Check the trace:

```
RuntimeError: invalid runtime
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
       require at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/activesupport-2.3.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184
        (root) at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql.rb:3
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
       require at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/mysql-2.8.1/lib/mysql.rb:68
          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
       require at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66
          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
       require at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55
       require at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/bundler-1.0.12/lib/bundler.rb:120
     load_gems at /Users/razenha/Projects/Pro/portaltrademarketing/config/boot.rb:116
       process at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/initializer.rb:164
          send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2052
           run at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/rails-2.3.10/lib/initializer.rb:113
        (root) at /Users/razenha/Projects/Pro/portaltrademarketing/config/environment.rb:12
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
       require at /Users/razenha/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29
        (root) at /Users/razenha/Projects/Pro/portaltrademarketing/config/environment.rb:47
       require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1038
       require at /Users/razenha/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29
        (root) at /Users/razenha/Projects/Pro/portaltrademarketing/spec/spec_helper.rb:1
          load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063
    load_files at ./spec/lib/importacao_atividades_spec.rb:15
          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1602
    load_files at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/rspec-1.2.9/lib/spec/runner/example_group_runner.rb:14
  run_examples at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/rspec-1.2.9/lib/spec/runner/options.rb:132
           run at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/rspec-1.2.9/lib/spec/runner/command_line.rb:9
        (root) at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/gems/rspec-1.2.9/bin/spec:5
          load at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1063
        (root) at /Users/razenha/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.6.1/bin/spec:19
```

So I am really stuck here. Anyone know how can I fix the nailgun issue? If not, is there an alternative? Is it possible to use spork in jruby and rails 2.3?

Comment: if you have the rep, please add the tag nailgun to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh... Looks like jruby does not like an older version of the Redis gem. Updated my Resque/Redis gem version and it worked.

Comment: How could you tell that was the problem?